# Color row until the sum of cell is equal to a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good day everyone,
I need to dynamically color rows of a table, until the sum of cells of a column reachs a certain value

[image: age]

The "Effort" column is column E. I need therefore need to color rows until the sum of column E value is 240. In this case, assuming that "Feature O" cell is in row 4, I would need to color until row 14 "Feature E" excluded. This table is subject to changes, as new rows might be added, or effort recalculated.

I hope it is clear enough so that you can help me.

Cheers.
Tommaso

---

Gents, your answer are very much appreciated.
Assuming now that I have a pool of resources available for a certain release. I need to color green up to a certain value, then, from there, need to color until another value is reached (a delta), and so on.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYvXO.png)

What I want to reach is to show how many items fits in a certain pool of resources, with the value on coloum K

I've tried the following, but after the green color, the formula is not correct: while the pool for the 2nd release is 153.6, the formatting colors the cells up to 168, instead of 153.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCqfg.png)

I hope it's clear,

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example on the assumption you need to color the cells unless the total sum would go above `240`:

[image]

- Select range `E4:E16`
- New conditional formatting rule by formula:

  ```
  =SUM($E$4:E4)<=240
  ```
- Choose format and apply

Now upon editing or adding:

[image]

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!

Comment: @Tommaso, glad it works, kindly upvote/accept as answer as described [here](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) if this has been usefull.

Comment: Done, but unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation, so my vote is not properly shown T.T

Answer (score 0):

*Since you are using TABLE therefore my approach is quite different to highlight rows, until the SUM is equals to certain value.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- You need to create one Helper Column.
- Enter Criteria `240` in Cell `N1`.
- Formula in Cell `N2`, fill it down:

  `=SUM(INDEX(Table1[Efforts],1):Table1[@Efforts])<=$N$1`
- Select entire Range `I2:N14`.
- Reach to **Conditional Formatting**, **New Rule** and apply this formula.

  `=$N2=TRUE`
- Apply an appropriate Color and finish with **Ok.**
- Then click **Conditional Formatting** then **Manager Rules**.
- Now using **Applies To** Combo box, select Range `J2:J14`, then hit **Apply** & finish with **Ok**.

[image]

- You get the effects on `Column J`.

**N.B.**

- Using Cell `N1` to match with criteria makes the exercise dynamic.

*If next is to highlight rows, until the `SUM` is equals to `14` or any value, then instead of redraw entire exercise, only replace the match value in cell `N1`, which saves the time too*.

[image]

- Later on for neatness you may hide Range `N2:N14` as well as adjust other parameters also.